# How to run multiple sudo commands over already opened ssh connection

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, sudo

I am trying to navigate from one server"USER1" to another using ssh as a user "USER2".

```
ssh -t $hostname "sudo su - USER2; whoami; pwd"
```

Post executing the above, I am able to successfully navigate to the server as USER2, but the trailing commands i.e "whoami and pwd" are not getting executed.However, while exiting the ssh session USER1 is rendered in the output followed by the present working directory.

I do not want to make any changes in the ssh known hosts file.

Comment: The command you wrote gives the behavior you got; `su` does not exit until you exit USER2's shell, at which point the next command(s) run (`whoami` and `pwd`). I don't see the "multiple sudo" commands from your post's title, though. What behavior do you want to see change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're executing the command `sudo su - USER2; whoami; pwd` on the remote host. Let's decompose that:

- Commands separated by a semicolon are executed in sequence. Thus the command `sudo su - USER2` is executed first; then, when it finishes, `whoami` is executed, and finally `pwd` is executed.
- The command `sudo su - USER2` starts a login shell as user USER2. This shell reads commands from standard input until it's told to exit (e.g. with the `exit` builtin) or until it detects an end of file on standard input. Since standard input is connected to the terminal, it waits for you to type commands.

If you want to execute commands as USER2, you need to pass them as arguments to `sudo`. Running `su` isn't useful here, sudo already knows how to do this. You don't need the `-t` option to SSH unless you want to interact with the remote commands (this includes the case when you need to type a password for sudo).

```
ssh -t "$remotehost" 'sudo -i -u USER2 sh -c "whoami; pwd"'
```

If your sudo configuration only allows you to run programs as root, not as an arbitrary user (which doesn't change anything security-wise), then you'll need to stick to `sudo su`. In that case, pass the `-c` option to `su` to run the specified shell command.

```
ssh -t "$remotehost" 'sudo su -c "whoami; pwd" USER2'
```

If you need to read the user's `.profile`, do so explicitly.

```
ssh -t "$remotehost" 'sudo su -c ". ~/.profile; whoami; pwd" USER2'
```

Alternatively, you can pass the commands as standard input to an interactive shell. The plumbing is a little delicate since ssh's standard input must remain the terminal. An advantage of this approach with a here document is that quoting in the shell command remains relatively simple: escape `'` as `'\''` for the remote shell, no escaping is needed for the remote shell.

```
ssh -t "$remotehost" 'sudo su - USER2 <<\EOF
whoami
pwd
EOF'
```

Comment: After running the command which you have suggested got following error.

sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

I tried ssh -t "$remotehost" 'sudo -i -u USER2' and got the following error

Sorry, user USER1 is not allowed to execute '/bin/ksh' as USER2 on 
remotehost.

The restrictions are as follows
I want to switch to USER2 first and then execute a set of commands on the remote host.

Comment: @dnup1092 If you need to type a password for sudo, then you do need the `-t` option. As for the error you're getting from sudo, that seems like a strange sudo configuration where you're only allowed to run programs as root. Change the configuration from `dnup0192 ALL=(root) ALL` to `dnup0192 ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`, the security impact is exactly the same.

Comment: I don't have the privilege to change the configuration.Is there any way out

Comment: @dnup1092 Then you'll need to keep using `sudo su` (see my edit).

Comment: @dnup1092 If you have the ability to use sudo to switch to root, then you have the ability to change the configuration.

Comment: @JennyD The technical ability, yes, but not necessarily the bureaucratic permission.

Comment: @Gilles I tried out the above suggested approches and the following are the conclusions for the same:
`1.ssh -t "$remotehost" 'sudo su -c "whoami; pwd" USER2'
result -Sorry, user USER1 is not allowed to execute '/bin/su -c whoami; pwd USER2' as root on remotehost.'

'2. ssh -t "$remotehost" 'sudo su - USER2' <<'EOF''
'whoami'
'pwd'
'EOF'
result - Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
USER1@remotehost's password:
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
`

Comment: Start by logging in and running `sudo -l` - that will tell you what permissions you have.

Comment: @dnup1092 So what permissions *do* you have then? Just the permission to run `su - USER2`? That's a silly configuration, but if you have to live with it, use the last alternative in my answer.

Comment: @Gilles I have only that much of permission :) .. I executed your third option as the way you have suggested but got the following:
`Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal`. Can you tell me what does this mean?

Comment: @dnup1092 Ah, I hadn't thought of that. `ssh -t` creates a terminal on the remote side; you need that to be able to type your password for sudo. But it can only do that if its standard input is the local terminal, so redirecting the input of SSH doesn't work. Instead, do the redirection inside the command executed by SSH. See my edit.

Comment: @Gilles thanks finally got it worked as expected... JennyD thanks for your input too

Comment: Probably I'm late to the party, and this is 'me too' comment... anyway, it's my favorite kind of SO answers: detailed, short, substantive. All's good :) Thx for your effort!